# How to get from Cockatoo, Victoria to the Melbourne CBD on public transport?

Tags: public-transport, melbourne, victoria-australia

We're in Cockatoo, Victoria and looking to get to downtown Melbourne on public transport.

Cockatoo is a country town but isn't really far from the suburbs these days. We know there's a bus from nearby but we don't know how far it can take us.

Maybe it can take us to the last train station out this way or maybe we'd need to change buses.

Everyone we know drives and doesn't know much about the buses out here but it's too far a drive to ask anyone to drive us in.

Google Maps doesn't seem to cover this far out from Melbourne for its directions.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a partial answer as I haven't figured out some of the details such as price and how and where to get a myki card, how long it takes, and when the last ride is possible...

[Bus 695 runs between Cockatoo and Belgrave Station](http://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/getting-around/maps/metropolitan-buses/view/1632). From there, a train on [the Belgrave line](http://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/getting-around/maps/metropolitan-buses/view/1632) might take about an hour into the city, depending on the time of day and which city stop.

Comment: The PTV website is pretty decent and should cover the bus routes, ticket prices, Myki purchase/topup locations, and train times. Did you manage to find what you needed here?

Comment: We ended up changing our plans from heading to the CBD to hitchhiking directly from Cockatoo to New South Wales.